# Xcode gif can not be used

Tags: xcode, gif

When I want to use a gif picture in Xcode , his status is unactive,and his color is gray, I don't know why. Who knows these questions.

Comment: Can you add the troubling gif and described what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support GIF by itself.

But you can use some third-party library to play gif in your project.

https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage